# Reproduce the look of TeamViewer 10

Tags: vb.net, forms

Is it possible to set two forms at the same "level" ?

In TeamViewer 10, when one of the two forms is selected, the other form is visible too. When we click on one of them, the clicked form and the other are both brought to front...

How can I reproduce the same working ?

I tried to override the `OnGotFocus` sub :

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnGotFocus(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnGotFocus(e)
    Form2.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

---

My goal is to create an app looking like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the **Owner** of the secondary form, by passing in the primary form to its `Show()` method:

```
' ... From within Form1 ...
Dim f2 As New Form2
f2.Show(Me) ' <-- setting Form1 as the owner of Form2
```

Now the two forms will act as a "unit".